# ASCII values in table

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I want to initialise the table with all the ascii characters i.e. at 65-A, 66-B ....

```
 Table abc;
for(int ascii=0;ascii<256;ascii++)
{
    string a;
    a=ascii;
    abc.insertvalue(a,ascii);
    //I have a class named table which has insertvalue function
}
```

The code shows error after inserting the 127th ascii character.
How can I modify it.

While debugging, it only printed till 127th position of array.

Comment: That would be so much clearer with a for loop.

Comment: Please provide a MCVE

Comment: ASCII is 0 .. 127.  I suggest you use `unsigned char` instead of `int`.  An `int` type means the value can go negative.  There are no negative values in the ASCII table.

Comment: The results here are very dependent on your terminal emulator's encoding.

Answer (score 3):

ASCII is a 7bit encoding. You should change the loop to `while (ascii < 128)`.

And use a `for` loop:

```
for (int ascii = 0; ascii < 128; ++ascii) {
    …
}
```